# Getting attributes for a property where there isn't a direct reference

Tags: c#

How do I get attributes of the Stuff property from the DoStuff() method? Is this possible?

```
public class Bar
{
    public enum FooZ
    {
        Hello,
        GoodBye
    }

    [Display("Hello"]
    public FooZ Stuff { get; set; }

    public Bar() {
        Stuff = FooZ.GoodBye;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var x = new Bar();

    DoStuff(x.Stuff);
}

void DoStuff(Enum z) {

    // How do I get the DisaplyAttribute from here?
}
```

Comment: The `DisplayAttribute` is associated to `Stuff` not `FooZ`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The parameter `z` doesn't remember where it came from; values don't remember how they were constructed. Remember that in this case, the **property** is what is decorated with the attribute (meaning that it is embedded in the containing-type's metadata), not the value returned by its getter. You have to reflect the `Bar` type itself, as in Itay's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Type t = typeof(Bar);
PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty("Stuff");
Attribute[] att = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true);
```

Comment: That's not what I asked. I'm aware of how to get properties using reflection like what you have shown. I need to know how to reach the attribute on the property from DoStuff()

Comment: You can put my code in `DoStuff` and it will reach the attribute. The attribute "belongs" to the type itself, not to its instances.